# Dynamically invoke method in c#

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I want to be able to store function reference and disregard arguments until it actually is used.

Here's what I'd like for it to look like:

```
StoreType f=MyFunction;
.......
var r=f.Invoke(arg1,arg2,arg3) as ReturnType;
```

This is kind of like Action and Func, but those are strongly typed, and I want to be able to declare and use this type without precisely knowing how many arguments and of what types the function will take.

How do I do this in c#?

Comment: Just out of interest: How do you know which parameters you need when actually invoking the method?

Comment: I don't. This is up to the end user

Comment: And how is he supposed to know? You may realize that it currently is a bit unclear what end goal you are trying to achieve. Everytime it is hard to do something, the first thing to ask yourself is: Am I doing this right?

Comment: This will be a part of a scripting language

Comment: @ArsenZahray - if it's part of a scripting language you're planning to write then it's not strictly a C# issue.

Comment: I'm going to do it in c#, and I'm interested in whether there is an easy and elegant way to do it

Comment: Have you tried declaring all the arguments as object or object[] and doing the casts inside the function body? That's the C#-y way to say 'i don't know what to expect here'.

Answer (score 1):

For the argument count, just pass an array of object containing the arguments.

```
f.Invoke(new object[]{ arg1, args2, args3, ... });
```

For the type use the method

```
Convert.ChangeType(objectToConvert, destinationType);
```

Should work for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the older `delegate` syntax.

`public delegate ReturnType MyFunction(string arg1, int arg2, ...);`

`var result = MyFunction.Invoke(arg1, arg2, ...);`